# Update a column with values of the same column in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

In postgres I would like to update as below.

My table `product` has these columns

- uuid
- sold
- product_id
- variant_id
- data

I would like to update the uuid of all the sold=true records with the uuid of the records with that product_id and variant_id.

For example

If this is my table
[image]

I would like to update the records with product_id=203 and variant_id = 1 to have the same uuid. And the records with product_id = 3242 and variant_id=3 to have the same uuid and so on.

How should the update query be like?

How should the update query be like? even if either of product_id or variant_id is NULL??

Postgresql version 10.3

Comment: Say that the first row with product_id = 3243 instead had NULL as product_id, what should happen when updating? Since variant_id is the same for product_id NULL, 3242 and 6630 how would you know which rows to update?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: Can only rows with sold = 'f' have null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UPDATE with a join to the same table. This query updates the rows where sold = 't', if I have misunderstood that you need to switch 't' and 'f' in the last two lines

```
UPDATE product AS p 
SET uuid = p2.uuid
FROM product p2
WHERE p2.product_id = p.product_id
  AND (p2.variant_id = p.variant_id  OR p2.variant_id IS NULL OR p.variant_id IS NULL)
  AND p.sold = 't'
  AND p2.sold = 'f'
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1b013abe0abc50cb269049ddb792c511)

Comment: This doesn't work if either the product_id is NULL or variant_id is NULL.

Comment: @Surya What does it mean when product_id is NULL, could those rows really be updated?

Comment: @Surya I have updated my answer to allow for variant_id to be null but not for product_id to be null because I don't understand how that is possible to perform a correct update then. Could you show some sample data with null values?

Comment: @Surya in your question you say *even if either of product_id or variant_id is NULL* isn't this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is no case for `product_id` and `variant_id` to be both `NULL`:

```
update product p1 set uuid = p2.uuid from product p2
where p1.sold = 't' and p2.sold = 'f'
  and (
    (p2.product_id = p1.product_id and p2.variant_id = p1.variant_id)
    or
    (p2.product_id IS NULL and p2.variant_id = p1.variant_id)
    or
    (p2.product_id = p1.product_id and p2.variant_id IS NULL)
  )
```